# Centered Message Box .NET - Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge 11.6 (32-bit)

Tags: .net, eclipse, progress-4gl, openedge

I've been looking for message alignment in Progress OpenEdge Documentation (https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/message-statement.html) and can't find it.

How to set message box centered with parent form in native way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't!

The long answer is that you might be able to call the win32 API and set up a message box in a specific way.

However a quick browse of the Win32 API (as well as .NET) reveals no ways of modifying default positions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx

A workaround might be to use a frame defined as a dialog-box.

This is a very quick and dirty code to get you started:

```
DEFINE BUTTON   b1   LABEL "OK".
DEFINE VARIABLE cMsg AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(30)" .

DEFINE FRAME fr1 
    cMsg NO-LABEL 
    b1
    cMsg AT COLUMN 1 ROW 1
    b1   AT COLUMN 5 ROW 3 
    WITH VIEW-AS DIALOG-BOX  SIZE 40 BY 5 
    .

ENABLE b1 WITH FRAME fr1.

ON "choose":U OF b1 
DO:
    MESSAGE "You pressed OK!" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    APPLY "close" TO FRAME fr1.
END.

/* Set the location */
FRAME fr1:ROW = 10.
FRAME fr1:COL = 30.

cMsg = "This is the message".

DISPLAY cMsg WITH FRAME fr1.

WAIT-FOR "close" OF FRAME fr1.
```

Comment: I thought so, it's impossible to do it in native way after all...
Actually, calling FRAME from class file(I forgot to mention before) is not possible unless it's still in .p format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx).

This should enable you to show the message in the desired location.

Comment: How? No options on that page seems to describe location. If you know it can be done you should describe how!

Comment: @Jensd. By parenting the message box to the parent form the default behaviour is to display the message in the center.

Comment: That should be the default behavior of the built in Progress message box as well. Perhaps I didnt read good enough when answering, thought it was about centering on the entire screen and not on the parent form.

Comment: @Peter Strachan. I have tried System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox but it centered on screen instead of parent form.

Comment: Apologies. I thought that was the whole point of parenting the message box. The only other way would be to create your own custom message box then. You can give it options to centre parent.

Comment: @PeterStrachan the most possible I thought is to make an inherited / new form with : 1. FormStyle : FixedDialog   |   2. put in a *label* also variable as character input for the label.    |    3. Set Form's StartPosition : CenterParent.     |    4. Set MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox to False